# Get rating with highest value in dictionary python

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I got a dictionary with some movies. I want to know what the highest rating (cijfer) is, and print the title and rating to the screen. See the dictionary for more info. I can not find the clue, can someone help me?

```
movies = [{"titel": "The Godfather", "jaar": 1972, "cijfer": 9.2, "regisseur": "Francis Ford Coppola"},
      {"titel": "The Shawshank Redemption", "jaar": 1994, "cijfer": 9.3, "regisseur": "Frank Darabont"},
      {"titel": "Schindler's List", "jaar": 1993, "cijfer": 8.9, "regisseur": "Steven Spielberg"},
      {"titel": "Raging Bull", "jaar": 1980, "cijfer": 8.2, "regisseur": "Martin Scorsese"},
      {"titel": "Casablanca", "jaar": 1942, "cijfer": 8.5, "regisseur": "Michael Curtiz"}]'''
```

Comment: Share your tries, SO is not a coding service ;)

Comment: This is simple enough to at least try some coding yourself before asking the question.

Answer (score 1):

Use `max(..., key=...)`:

```
best_movie = max(movies, key=lambda m: m["cijfer"])
print(best_movie["titel"], best_movie["cijfer"])
```

Comment: Wow i thought it was way more difficult, it works thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're not very proficient with Python if you are asking this, so I share a "understable" way to do it for a begginer.

```py
max_rating = 0
idx_best_rating = 0
    for index, movie in enumerate(movies):
        if movie['cijfer'] >= max_rating:
            idx_best_rating = index
            max_rating = movie['cijfer']
best = movies[idx_best_rating]
```

A cleaner way:

```
best = max(movies, key=lambda movie: movie["cijfer"])
```

Comment: Can you please explain the cleaner way for our understanding

Comment: @NanduRaj You use Python's max() function to get the maximum element in the list. Also, the "key" parameter corresponds to a lambda function (movie) which is used by the max function to compare the elements in the list. In this case, we compare by it's rating (cijfer).